# Drupal 7 form message not displaying in custom page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am using drupal 7 and I have a custom page page--user--login.tpl.php where login form and registration form are present in the same page.

When I click the "Sign in" button without filling in the fields, it is only highlighting the required fields. Error message is displayed when the "Sign in" button is clicked the second time only.

The code I used in page--user--login.tpl.php is as follows:

```
<?php
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
?>
```